# What is ‘redness’ and ‘blueness,’ abstract nouns or concrete nouns?

Tags: abstract-nouns

What is ‘redness’ and ‘blueness,’ abstract nouns or concrete nouns? I think we can see redness and blueness, but they say words for qualities are abstract nouns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see redness itself. You can see an object, or a beam of light, and discern whether it is red, but that does not mean the same thing as "seeing redness." If you could somehow "see redness," that would imply that you are looking, not at any one instance of a red object, but at the quality or property which *all* red objects share. But you can't look at such a shared property, because it is not a physical object, in the same way that the number three is not a physical object. So we say that redness is an abstract noun.

Incidentally, there are some philosophers who doubt the existence of abstract objects such as redness altogether, but that's another discussion. If you want to argue this point, I suggest doing [some research](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/) and then, if you're still confused, taking it to [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com).